# Wordpress can't load Media

Tags: wordpress, media

i have some issue with the Media. I can still upload (images and files) and see them at the Media Site but when i try to attache them to a Site it shows me nothing! The Media is loading but will not load one image...

img: [image](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4090/gwu24jof_jpg.htm)
This is what i see all the time.

I setted some Backups up online and offline. With the Backup of the 11.08 everything seems to be fine it work well. With the Backup of the 20.08 the issue is appearing. I tried to reinstall the Core of WordPress, delete over 3000 Files the backup is down to 5000 Media Files, deactivate all Plugins and nothing seems to work. We did not update wordpress or changed something in the time just uploaded Images into the woocommerce Shop.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks

ps.: I get no error.

Comment: I think your images are not uploading due to upload size. Try to upload image with smaller size and check.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. The Images where uploading they were shown in the Media Library.
The Problem was a script in my Function.php of my Theme. I still don't understand why a script for displaying a Customfield in the Admin panel is killing my Sites Connection to the Media but as long as it is working now.

Comment: You don't need to write any function for admin panel. What you have done in front-end to show images? Share your code.

Comment: I used the script to add the "quick edit" function to a custom Column in my Woocommerce product grid.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/27269504/4815181
This is the link to the Thread